# Is it possible to send emails via GMAIL RESTful APIs without having a copy in Sent Folder?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Thank you all in advance.

Is it possible to send an email via the GMAIL RESTful API (https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=media) without saving a copy in the sent folder?

I have seen implementations in Outlook (Exchange/REST/Graph APIs) where emails can be sent without having copies in the sent folder. I was wondering if this is possible with the GMail APIs as well.

Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround:**

Currently, sending an email using Gmail API will always create a copy in the SENT folder, but one workaround you can do is:

1. Get the current timestamp `timestamp` before sending the message.
2. Send the message using `messages.send`.
3. Call `users.messages.list` with query parameter `labelIds=SENT` (note: this is case-sensitive) and `?q=in:sent after:<timestamp>` to list the most recent sent message.
4. Call `users.messages.delete` and use the ID fetched from the previous call as the parameter.

**References:**

[Method: users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)

[Method: users.messages.delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/delete)